# DynamoDB transactions exceeding items limit

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I need to create dynamodb transactions with more than 100 items using C#

Hi All, I need to create dynamodb transactions with more than 100 items using C#. As it appears on the documentation, 100 items per request is the limit on Dynamo transactions.
My request will have n- elements , n > 100, and I need to commit all or nothing. How could I handle this scenario? Is there any design pattern I could apply?
If the first 100 items succeed, but not the following elements, I need to keep track of this and roll back committed items.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not just check before running the transaction the size of the batch and if its over 100 then do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Transaction limit was only recently increased to 100. If you have a dependency on more than 100 items then easiest workaround is to merge the items into a larger item to bring the dependency less than 100.

Otherwise you would have to roll your own transaction coordinator where you handle the state of all the items and implement rollback logic. It would get really tricky so I'd avoid that if possible.