Handling rollbacks while inserting records to DynamoDB
I'm currently inserting data to dynamoDB database using transactWrite. Transactions are only allowed for a batch of small chunk (let's say 100) but I want to add 500 items in the database in a All-or-none basis. I'm using transactWrite in loop with batches of 100 each. I am able to stop the transactions at the point where I get an error but not able to rollback the transactions that have already committed?
Can someone explain how to handle this scenario?

Encountered this problem before but I afraid no good solution. You might find these resources helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730832/dynamodb-transactions-exceeding-items-limit?rq=2
and this
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/18thskl/dynamodb_transactions_exceeding_items_limit/

Can you please provide more details on the use case? You might not use the right data store as DDB is best for LOOKUP, not logs. Do you have a key that is shared across all the "transaction" records? You might be able to use it to clean up failed transactions.

Transactions have only recently been increased to 100 from 25. Having a dependency on 500 items is almost an anti-pattern in DynamoDB as it aims to provide predictable performance at scale.
There is huge complexity in doing what you're trying to do. The best approach is probably merge those items into larger ones if they are truly dependent.

@Hannigan Any other solution if I don't merge them into large record?

My solution would be to use Aurora or something that gives you long running transactional statements. The complexity involved to do this in DynamoDB outweigh the pros.
